# Docker-Compose: Tomcat should wait to start until (My)SQL Dump is ready

Tags: docker, docker-compose

In my Docker-Compose.yml I have defined a Tomcat (including a .war-File) and MySQL-Server Image.
When I use docker-compose up - the MySQL-Server starts and is importing a SQL-Dump. The Tomcat is starting too.

Every time i run docker-compose up there can be other SQL-Skripts (due to a Jenkins-Build-Job which pulls scripts from a gitlab repo)

But I wish to have the Tomcat waiting for finishing the Import of all the SQL-Dumps to start.

Anybody knows how to do this?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Here in the official docks is a nice paragraph about it. If it isn't enough to use depends_on, you should incorporate the waiting aspect in your tomcat's start script. 
https://docs.docker.com/compose/startup-order/

Comment: Thanks for your help. But Compose will not wait until a container is “ready”  - only until it’s running. I already use the depends_on command. Do you have any Idea - how to do that in the tomcat start script?

Comment: @adbo Depends command checks if the container is running, a wait-for-it script will check when a service inside a container is running. (after the mysql start).

Comment: @adbo You can use the wait for it script inside your tomcat, to check when it can connect to the desired mysql stuff, when it's possible to connect you can start the real tomcat service.

Comment: Do you want to install mysql client in your tomcat container? Or you can write a java jar to do that?

Comment: @TarunLalwani How can a mysql-client help me?

Comment: @adbo with mysql-client in your tomcat container you can try to make a connection using the client to your mysql database. When the connection works you can start the tomcat service.: https://github.com/lvthillo/docker-php-postgres/tree/master/app It's an example for postgres with postgresclient installed in a php app. It uses the client + the wait for it script to connect to postgres, when it succeeds the php service starts.

Comment: How does the Tomcat Container know, that he can only start when the connection succeeds? It is perhaps a silly question but dont understand this.

Comment: @adbo, you implement something like https://github.com/vishnubob/wait-for-it

Comment: @adbo Check the wait-for-it script in the git repo I provided. In short it contains: Until you can not make a connection to the database: sleep one second and retry, when the connection works: execute your cmd (which is in the Dockerfile) = start the service of your apache-php (in this case tomcat) container.

Comment: @Ivthillo But, I want to wait until the SQL-Dump was imported. Even the Import isn't finished I can connect to the mysql-server via mysql-client. So Tomcat do not wait for finishing the Import.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're using docker-compose version 2, you can specify a healthcheck for your mysql container, and then use `condition: service_healthy` in your `depends_on` section.  e.g. something like

```
services:
  db:
    image: mysql:5.7
    healthcheck:
      test: mysql --protocol=socket -hlocalhost -uroot -p$$MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD -e 'SELECT 1'

  tomcat:
    image: tomcat
    depends_on:
      db:
        condition: service_healthy
```

See https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-file-v2/#depends_on

This is unsupported in docker-compose 3, so we currently use docker-compose 2 to avoid this issue.

Comment: Okay this means I can write in - e something like: -e 'SELECT example from table ' and example would be the last inserted sql statement? Then tomcat is waiting until the service is healthy. And the service is healthy when the Select statement was successfull?

Comment: @adbo - yes this should work - `SELECT 1` will wait until the database is initialised, or you can construct a SQL statement which will fail until all your scripts have run.

Comment: thank you. I think its the right answer, but doesn't help in my case. Because every time i run docker-compose up there can be other SQL-Skripts (due to a Jenkins-Build-Job which pulls scripts from a gitlab repo) - so i am unable to design a SQL statement which fails until all my scripts have run.

Comment: This sounds difficult.  One possible solution I can think of is that you could get your scripts to insert a row into a special table once they've finished.  So you could check for the existence of that row in your healthcheck.  Or it could just drop a file onto the filesystem which your healthcheck could check for the existence of.

Comment: Finally got it to work ;-). I was thinking about the same solution: Getting my scripts to insert a row into a special table once they've finished. Had to insert a timeout and retrie option to the healthcheck, so the check is done every minute.  (See my changes in your answer). Thank you very much for your help.